# Pgbadger 12.2 - generate report from cloud postgres logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pgbadger

I am having pgbadger(12.2) which is working fine with standalone for on-premise database postgres logs. It also works for csv files generated by query logging enabling.

I want to generate the same reports for postgres logs from GCP database. I generated postgres log from gcp which come in below format

```
insertId,labels.INSTANCE_UID,labels.LOG_BUCKET_NUM,logName,receiveLocation,receiveTimestamp,resource.labels.database_id,resource.labels.project_id,resource.labels.region,resource.type,severity,textPayload,timestamp
s=df070e37645bb400c9bfcytrc7fbhf9b9;i=474a5a1;b=1f9fbubfkey1476aa63hfifk724ec702;m=1ceuuuhs88e;t=65666703e363d;x=bd4d6d27c51d2c0e-0@a5,1-ee92b881-0982-4556-bf81-60d9c9d03d02,66,projects/mydb/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fpostgres.log,,2023-09-12T03:25:57.880009807Z,myhdb:gcuscdmsprddb01,myhdb,us-central,cloudsql_database,INFO,"2023-09-12 03:25:57.320 UTC [2963945]: [1442-1] db=600083,user=dms_pgsql_prod STATEMENT:  SELECT QUERY LIMIT 250 OFFSET 1500",2023-09-12T03:25:57.320484Z
```

Tried to generate pgbdger report but it shows nothing in html report.

```
D:\pgbadger-12.2>perl pgbadger D:\logs-20230816-174910.csv -o D:\report.html
[========================>] Parsed 14887360 bytes of 14887240 (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0
LOG: Ok, generating html report...
```

Also tried with JSON format but got empty html report again.

```
D:\pgbadger-12.2>perl pgbadger -f jsonlog D:\logs-20230816-182502.json -o D:\report.html
[========================>] Parsed 18307150 bytes of 18307150 (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0
LOG: Ok, generating html report...
```

I noticed that cloud csv format is very much different that usual postgres logs. kindly Suggest how to fix the issue or steps to use pgbedger for gcp postgres logs.

Comment: Another point against cloud hosted PostgreSQL.

Comment: That looks like an app server log, not a database log.  You should probably tag your question with something about GCP, since your question is not about plain PostgreSQL.